# @Page Title is ignored

Tags: asp.net

Every page in my ASP.NET application is based on `Main` masterpage, which in its turn is based on another `Base` masterpage (nested masterpages). I try to set different title for every page. I tried two approaches, but it does not work without any obvious reason.

1st attempt: `<%@ Page Title="ABC" ....... %>`. I do not know why, but it does nothing. No `<title>` tag is generated in resulting HTML.

2nd attempt: `<%@ Page meta:resourcekey="PageTitle" ....... %>` and `PageTitle.Title` to .resx. Same here. No `<title>` tag at all.

What did I miss?

Comment: Is there any error that you are getting ?

Comment: @Denis try to remove Title from Master page & try again.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the reason: looong time ago I removed `runat="server"` from my `<head>` tag. When I add it back - the `Title` directive starts to work, but it breaks other functionality, like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/<%= www.Utils.LanguageName %>/language14.css" />`.